# Setting Pixels Quickly

Tags: python, performance, graphics

I have searched and searched for a good answer and I am about to cry from frustration. I am a hobbyist programmer, I don't do things because they make sense, or they are the right way to do them; I do them to learn how, and right now I am stumped.

I want to set individual pixels on the screen. This may sound easy, but it's my other conditions that makes it hard. I need to do this quickly, CPU only, 20 fps or better (with other program elements running of course), on a 400 by 300 screen or better (full screen?).

I have been rendering some cool images using programs I wrote in Python that uses Pygame, but it takes 50 milliseconds to fill a 100px by 100px screen with just random pixels (that's my 20 fps right there, and other program bits slow it down more). Ideally I would LOVE to make my own (crappy) 3D game that just uses the CPU only, setting pixels on the screen (perhaps a voxel octree sort of graphics).

Is there any way (with any language, but preferably Python) I could like, make a 2D array of pixel values (more like 3D array with RGB) (is this called a bitmap?) in the RAM and dump it on to the display or something? Wouldn't that be fast??? How DO you interface directly with the pixels on a window. Argh! I am so clueless. I am / am not a programming noob. Give me whatever you can throw at me, I can digest it. I just need some pointers (haha) in the right direction.

Comment: Things haven't really worked that way on desktop computers for many years. There are many layers of virtualization in your way.

Comment: Yeah. Abstraction should be easy to throw aside. I just read an article claiming that DOS survived for games into the late 90s because you could write to the screen in 2 lines of C. With abstractions that can become 100s of lines. -.-

Comment: So, how can I get through this abstraction? Should I mess around with making DOS programs? That will work on a modern machine, right?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that you don't need to drop down to DOS to get 20 fps on a 400x300 pixel window on a modern machine.

Comment: Please don't add back the tags "set pixel ram quick".  The "set" tag is for mathematical sets, and "pixel", "ram", and "quick" are not useful for categorizing the topic of the question.  Remember that each tag should be relevant *by itself*; they're not a sentence.

Comment: For all its short comings, it should be easiest to do, in Flash.

Comment: No, it's definitely not acceptable to have to use DOS for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make your own "for each pixel" math (as opposed to just moving circles and bitmaps around), you will have to do it in C (or C++) to get anywhere close to machine speed.

On the other hand, if you want to make a full game, it will not be fun to write it all in a low-level language like C. You will need to combine fast C code with some some high-level scripting language. With Python you can bridge to a C extension module via numpy, or you can embed a language like Lua into C code, or you can try (oh horror) to learn high-level coding in C++. Either way things will get complex.

If you just want to play around with fast pixel rendering, I reccommend to use SDL (that's what pygame uses internally) but with C or C++ only. Follow a tutorial like [this one](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2003/05/15/sdl_anim.html) and have some fun.

If you want to stay within the comfort of Python, I suggest you try a 2D game first (loading and moving around bitmaps) or experiment with cairo (render geometric shapes).

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but the success to get it all running so quickly is your own merit :-)

Comment: It's definitelyh going to work for me, I just need to figure out Python bindings. Funny thing though, when I tried it the first time, I used an array of char in C for the data that I set the pixels to. I drew a green circle by setting certain values in the array. I got these weird patterns of dots that didn't belong in my image. When I made sure to set every single value in my array, it worked without a hitch. Did the program allocate free RAM to the array that still had left over garbage in it? Was I seeing old discarded data that hadn't been written over?

Comment: If you really want to integrate the C code with Python, I have some example code about this: https://github.com/martinxyz/python/ It should be possible to hook this up with pygame.surfarray. But just to warn you, this is not a well-trodden trail yet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to get over 20 fps at a resolution of (1920,1080) with pygame.

As Mallett pointed out, you should be using the pygame.surfarray.blit_array() function to copy the pixel data to pygame, and then update the screen with a call to pygame.display.flip().

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('pygame.surfarray.blit_array(screen, pixels);pygame.display.flip()', setup='import pygame;import numpy as np;size=(1920,1080);screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size);pixels=np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.uint32).max,size=size).astype(np.uint32)', number=20)
0.6346819400787354
>>> timeit.timeit("""
... pygame.surfarray.blit_array(screen, pixels)
... pygame.display.flip()
... """,setup="""
... import pygame
... import numpy as np
... size=(1920,1080)
... screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
... pixels=np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.uint32).max,size=size).astype(np.uint32)
... """, number=20)
0.4848361015319824
```

Comment: Ah cool, I've been working with C because I got SDL to work, but it's such a pain. I'm going to try this Python solution now! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do for PyGame is use pygame.surfarray or pygame.pixelarray.  After you set the values in the array, then you copy them all at once.  If you read the documentation about surface.set_at(...), which sets pixels individually, you'll see that it's not recommended for all but the smallest tasks.

pygame.surfarray and pygame.pixelarray are typically based on NumPy or Numeric (use NumPy).  Googling produces http://pygame.org/docs/tut/surfarray/SurfarrayIntro.html, which will give you a basic overview of some of the great things you can do.

Comment: Hey! This is helpful too! I was muddling through C, maybe I'll get the performance I need with Python. Python is SO much easier than C. Still, I'll have to compare the two. If C gets better performance, I'll stick with it (at least until I explode from frustration).

Comment: C will definitely give you more speed.  Like, make one, two orders of magnitude.  And it's not because Python was poorly designed or something; interpreted languages, by virtue of their architecture, simply **must** be slower.

Comment: Not true, my friend. Have a look at [http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/08/pypy-is-faster-than-c-again-string.html](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/08/pypy-is-faster-than-c-again-string.html)

Comment: . . . for equivalent tasks.  That link describes compiler/interpreter optimizations.  If libc were compiled with the C program, instead of being statically linked, then the compiler would be able to optimize it in the same way that PyPy did.<br/>In this case, PyPy was able to make semantic changes that did not affect the output, so as to increase speed, but the C compiler wasn't.  So, effectively, two different programs were being compared.  The comparison is like saying that a sprinter always beats a car in a race, simply because in your experiment the sprinter had a tremendous head start.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote Is there any way (with any language, but preferably Python) I could like, make a 2D array of pixel values (more like 3D array with RGB) (is this called a bitmap?) in the RAM and dump it on to the display or something?

Yes, this is called a [Frame Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer). You draw the bitmap in memory and then swap that memory into display memory.

Comment: I have all of the heavy math done. You'd be surprised to see my 3D math module I bet. I've got all the matrix/phong shading/etc. stuff down. Unfortunately, pygame is just too slow with setting the pixels.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have assumed, I removed that text from the answer.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I'd say the same thing to anybody asking me for advice. I ported my whole matrix math library to C a while ago because I've decided to do all of my graphics in that language. It was a big pain and took hours :/

Answer (score 0):

You must look into [bitblit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) , Though I have not done bit-blit in python, googling for it gave promising results.
Here is a related discussion from *Graphics gems* [p.134](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fvA7zLEFWZgC&lpg=PA134&dq=bit%20blit&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q=bit%20blit&f=false), where they discuss similar problem.

Comment: I asked about setting pixels, not bliting. I already know how to do bliting and I already know that it is super fast compared to setting pixels.